# Как выглядит и работает цикл while в Python?

Tags: python, циклы, while

Приведите пример цикла `while` в python. Как он выглядит, как работает, какие есть особенности по сравнению с другими языками программирования?

*P.S. Вопрос, конечно, примитивный, но для новичка и это может быть сложно и непонятно.*

Comment: Поищите в интернете статьи на эту тему — они помогут намного больше, нежели можем мы здесь, в комментариях и ответах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while` - это цикл*, который повторяет что-то, пока условие верно. Например**:

```
count = 0
flag = True
while flag == True: #это цикл, который делает то, что отмечено отступом пока flag == True.
   if count == 15:
       break    #если сount равен 15, выходить из цикла while.
   print("пока верно")
   count += 1
```

---

*-цикл - что-то, что повторяется.

**-после # показаны комментарии, это не код.

Надеюсь, стало понятно!

Comment: Мне кажется, если человек приходит сюда с такими вопросами - значит он либо просто поленился загуглить, либо - не понимает того, что написано в интернете. А просто кусок кода на такой вопрос не несет почти никакой пользы.

Comment: @Стас Согласен) ну я сделал свое дело)

Comment: А за что минус?

Comment: Минус не мой, наверно человек пришел, согласился со мной и поставил минус

Comment: @Стас ясно) спасибо)

Comment: Пробел перед скобкой ((

Comment: Инкремент в начале цикла?

Comment: а за что минусы? Что я просил, то он и сделал!

Comment: @Егор спасибо! Хоть вы меня поддерживаете!

Comment: @Стас, если все будут **хорошо гуглить**, то вопросов тут **не будет** (и вы тут станете не нужны...)

Comment: @avp Скажу только про метки, по которым активно отвечаю. Когда начинал, то было 3-4 вопроса в день, на которые можно было ответить. Теперь, после того, как больше половины ответил да ещё своих с самоответами подкинул, дай бог 3-4 в неделю. Почему? Да потому, что они **хорошо гуглятся**. И вот я стал почти **не нужным**. А что в этом плохого, результат то вроде достигнут?

Comment: @0xdb, не в том направлении ищете результат. Вы наверное тоже считаете, что цель это БазаЗнаний?

Comment: @avp А в каком-то направлении его надо искать? Цель была, помочь как можно большему числу коллег, ищущих решение для своих задачь. И если я пытаюсь достичь этого, то это оказывается плохо?

Comment: @0xdb, согласен. Помочь конкретному человеку это всегда хорошо. Если эти ответы помогли еще кому-нибудь -- прекрасно. Так что, речь не о вашем вкладе, а о комментарии -- *`"...если человек приходит сюда с такими вопросами - значит он либо просто поленился загуглить, либо - не понимает того, что написано в интернете. А просто кусок кода на такой вопрос не несет почти никакой пользы..."`* от которого так и веет пренебрежением к конкретному вопросу конкретного человека

Comment: @avp Да, всё верно, но я же отвечал на ваш комментарий - _то вопросов тут не будет и вы тут станете не нужны_, который воспринимается негативно. Не всегда, если что-то исчезает и кто-то становится в связи с этим не нужным, это плохо, чаще наоборот.

Comment: @0xdb, вот тут мы и подобрались к сути -- а именно, так чего мы в идеале хотим от нашего сайта? imho это клуб профессионалов, в котором вопрос порождает развивающийся разговор в виде разнообразных ответов  на заданную тему (и около нее). Такой разговор, который было бы **интересно** слушать, а при наличии чего-то своего и другим о нем *увлекательно* поведать. (ага, сам понимаю, что мы бесконечно далеки от такого времяпровождения -))

Comment: @avp Ну своим комментарием, начать диспут на эту глобальную тему, да ещё под чужим закрытом вопросом, я не собирался. Для этого лучше на мету. Может 
 у вас появится время и желание там открыть заново тему: "Зачем вы здесь?".

Comment: @0xdb, сегодня точно нет, а завтра ... (ну да, все лентяи говорят завтра -))